# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged not executed after sign-in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created users on firebase by using:
the Firebase Admin SDK (in python). The users show up in the firebase console.

Now I am trying to log the user in using javascript on a login page. However, when I run the code shown below it always ends up in the `else` loop in my script, which I think indicates that the the user is not logged in.

The desired behavior is:
User enters email/password, they submit form, it logs them in, and then it redirects them to the index page. Instead it doesn't do anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.5.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
      const firebaseConfig = {
              //my stuff here
          };
  
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
    
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <form id="loginform" action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label> <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required="required" type="text" value="cameron.snow@gmail.com">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label> <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', loginUser);
        function loginUser(){
          let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
          let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
          firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(e=>{
              alert(e)
            });
        };
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
          if(user){
            console.log(user)
            user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
              //save the token in a cookie  
              document.cookie = "token=" + token;
              window.location.href = "/";
            });
            } else{
              console.log("What up dude?");
            }
          });
    </script>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

*edit:
I have checked that in the script that my `email` and `password` variables are working correctly. I have also checked that the:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(e=>{
              alert(e)});
```

piece is working as well and the return is what I expect... so the issue has to be in the `onAuthStateChanged()` part.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `if(user){` in the auth state changed handler and sign in, does it get to that breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add `window.location.href = "/";` in the `onAuthStateChanged()` as that will create an infinite loop of re-rendering into the index page.

Instead, you should redirect to the index page directly after a successful login process

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(()=> {
    window.location.href = "/";
}).catch(e=>{
              alert(e)});
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on the answer, it is to do as above, and only remove the redirect from the 'firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged' part.